# JPA entity not being created with default value with migration query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am adding a new column, `signature`, to my existing `user` table -- using FlyawayDB for DB migration -- where the new column will have a default value, for both new and existing users. However, I noticed that when I try creating and saving a new user, that field is null for some reason.

I don't know if is this is some caching issue (e.g. it's using some version of the user object before my `V2__adding_signature.sql` migration query is executed) or if something else.

Here is what I have:

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamicUpdate
public class UserEntity {
  @Id private String userId;

  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String signature;

  public UserEntity(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

  private final UserRepository userRepo;

  @Transactional
  public UserEntity createUser(String userId) {
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity(userId);
    userRepo.saveAndFlush(userMappingEntity);
    return userEntity; // this will not have a the default signature created
  }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, String> {

....
}
```

Initial PostGres DB set up in my db.migration folder (for Flywaydb)

**V1__initial_creation.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  user_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

**V2__adding_signature.sql**

```
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD COLUMN signature TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'testValueForNow';
```

EDIT_1:

I have also tried to use the EntityManager to fresh my entity, like so

```
  @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

      @Transactional
      public UserEntity createUser(String userId) {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity(userId);
        userRepo.saveAndFlush(userEntity);
        entityManager.refresh(userEntity);

        return userEntity; // this will not have a the default signature created
      }
```

however this doesn't seem to work either, and gives me the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed`

EDIT_2:
Thanks to user @Simon Martinelli

I had to do the following to get it to work:

```
   UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity(userId);
   userEntity = userRepo.saveAndFlush(userEntity);
   entityManager.refresh(entityManager.merge(userEntity));
   return userEntity;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value only applies in the database.

After insert you have to refresh the entity to get the inserted default value from the database.

Comment: What would the proper way of refreshing the entity be exactly? I have tried adding an EntityManager and then refreshing my entity via:   @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;
      entityManager.refresh(userEntity); but that seems to give me an HTTP 409 for some reason..

Comment: actually it returns a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed

Comment: Do you call persist or merge? If merge you have to pass the entity that merge returned

Comment: I tried:       entityManager.refresh(entityManager.merge(userEntity)); after I save and flushed the entity

Comment: How do you save?

Comment: userRepo.saveAndFlush(entity)

Comment: entityManager.refresh(userRepo.saveAndFlush(entity))

Comment: oh! that helped! I actually had to saveAndFlush, then merge that object, and then refresh via userMappingEntity = userRepo.saveAndFlush(userMappingEntity);
      entityManager.refresh(entityManager.merge(userMappingEntity)); THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `@Generated` [annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-Generated) for the `signature` field in this way:

```java
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String signature;
```

So, hibernate will be able to fetch the property after the entity has been persisted or updated.

Another one piece of your problem is the following code:

```
@Transactional
public UserEntity createUser(String userId) {
   UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity(userId);
   userRepo.saveAndFlush(userMappingEntity);
   return userEntity; // this will not have a the default signature created
}
```

It is correct when you know for sure that a user with `userId` does not exist. *But when the user with `userId` is actually present in the database the column `signature` does not fetch.* So, you should correct this method in this way:

```java
@Transactional
public UserEntity createUser(String userId)
{
   Optional<User> user = userRepo.findById(userId);
   if (user.isPresent()) return user.get();

   UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity(userId);
   return userRepo.save(userEntity);
}
```

I guess that `saveAndFlush` can be replaced by `save` because the flushing will be done anyway in the end of `createUser` method as it marked as `@Transactional`.

Comment: I just tried that hibernate annotation but it is still, unfortunately, not generating the signature. I also tried to refresh the cache, in addition to that, via  entityManager.refresh(entityManager.merge(userEntity)); but still no luck for some reason..

Comment: Actually my suggestion should work. Please try to use it with suggested correction of the `createUser` method.